# How to avoid file_get_content/fgets/fread from separating my string?

Tags: php, string, encoding, openssl

I have a .txt file that I generate using openssl base 64, let's say the content of the file is:

Hik+W9hsOweQdOYx0ngYn+O54lXiDjZvDdzjtBwTI/uhPKF5egIIXnau3535G3wOyZnsI6F3YgokDfc9m6O3UM7MBMqgG5TEqtPdCzSbFq9VUPdJSmznNVQCI207OMku9NNLgehkh/jK2eITpPuh97EQuCW/aJjl0quM07bhWiI=

All in one line, but even when I copied it from notepad and pasted it here, it pasted like 3 lines:

Hik+W9hsOweQdOYx0ngYn+O54lXiDjZvDdzjtBwTI/uhPKF5egIIXnau3535G3wO
yZnsI6F3YgokDfc9m6O3UM7MBMqgG5TEqtPdCzSbFq9VUPdJSmznNVQCI207OMku
9NNLgehkh/jK2eITpPuh97EQuCW/aJjl0quM07bhWiI=

I've been trying to trick the string by separing it but no matter what I try it just doesn't work, I've tried the next:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$str = "";
while($line = fgets($handle)){
    echo $line; <--here i get 3 strings separated by a space characters
    $str = $str.$line; 
fclose($handle);
echo $str; <--- same 3 strings separated by a space
die;
```

Then tried:

```
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $str2 = "";
$str = fread($handle, filesize($file)); <-same result
fclose($handle);
echo substr($str,0,64);  
echo substr($str,64,64);
echo substr($str,128);  <-same result
    $str2 = substr($str,0,64).substr($str,64,64).substr($str,128); <-same result
```

And I actually first tried this one, as this was supposed to be the easiest way to get a file content:

```
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
echo $str;   <- same result
```

Trying to replace ' ' by '', and it not working, lead me to believe that even if there is one single string in the .txt file, somehow the base64 encoding makes these strings special and worst of all, php knows it and can't ignore it, but I need it to be 1 single string, anybody knows what's happening and mind explaining it? And how can I accomplish getting 1 string without the spaces every 64 characters? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: so the .txt file that you are generating creates 3 separate strings but you would like to combine them into 1?  Do you mind sharing the openssl command you are using to generate your string?

Comment: No, the .txt has only 1 string, but when I get the content of the file, it gets 3 strings, even when I copied it directly from the notepad and pasted it here it was 3 string, but in notepad it shows 1 string, no spaces, no new lines, this is the command: openssl base64 -in $bin -out $file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the base64 section of http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities:

> "warning base64 line length is limited to 76 characters by default in
>   openssl ( **and generated with 64 characters / line** ) ... to be able to
>   decode a base64 line without line feed that exceed 76 characters use
>   -A option :"

this means that your command:

> openssl base64 -in $bin -out $file

will automatically break your output up into 64 character lines

if you would like the output to be in one line use the -A option:

> openssl base64 -A -in $bin -out $file

this will make your output all 1 large string

reading that into your php script with file_get_contents() should get you your desired results.

this wiki page does say this about the -A option though:

> "... -A option is BUGGY ( limit with long files )."

though it does not appear specify how long a "long file" is.

---

If you would like to stick with your original openssl command:

> openssl base64 -in $bin -out $file

then try this to make it all one string:

```
$str = file_get_contents($file);
$str = str_replace("\n", "", $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, I knew there was something but I had no idea how to look for it. I prefer avoiding the buggy part, so I went for the string replace and worked like a charm, thank you!